# Change the column background colour based on the result of a Ajax return

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is the second time I have posted on this issue. I have deleted the first post to try and make this easier to read.

I need to change the background colour of a dataTables column based on the return of an ajax return. If the ajax returns `[{"BoardName":"Main reception","Status":1}]`, I would like the background colour of the column to be green, else be red.

The MySQL

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$sql = "SELECT RecordID, RoomName  FROM ConfBookings2017 WHERE HotelID = '".$_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid']."' AND FullDb = 1";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
$TotalRcount = $res->num_rows;
$data = array();
if($TotalRcount > 0) {  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $BoardName = $row['RoomName'];
    $Rcount = 1; 
    $data[] = array(
            "BoardName" => $BoardName,
                    "Status"    => $Rcount);
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $BoardName = "No overrides active";
    $Rcount = 0;
    $data[] = array(
                    "BoardName" => $BoardName,
                    "Status"    => $Rcount);
 echo json_encode($data);   
}
```

The script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#WayFinderOverrideStatusTable').DataTable( {      
   ordering: false,
   paging: false,
   searching: false,
   bInfo : false,
   responsive: true,
   fixedHeader: true,
   scrollX: false,
   pageResize: true,
   ajax: {
      url: 'check_wayfinder_override.php', 
      dataSrc: ''
   },
    columns: [
      { data: 'BoardName',"sWidth": "100%" },
      { data: 'Status',"visible": false  },
      
    ],
    rowCallback: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    console.log("Log 1");
    if ( data[1] == 1 ) {    
    console.log("Log 2");    
      $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('WayFinderOverrideStatusOn');
    } else {
    console.log("Log 3");
      $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('WayFinderOverrideStatusOff');
    }
  },
}); 
  setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
  }, 30000 ); 
});
```

The CSS

```
.WayFinderOverrideStatusOn {
    color: #333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding-left: 5px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background-color: #FFD7D7;
    border-bottom-width: 0.5px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #999;
}

.WayFinderOverrideStatusOff {
    color: #333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding-left: 5px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background-color: #E1FFE1;
    border-bottom-width: 0.5px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #999;
}
```

After testing in the browser debugger it appears that the `if ( data[1] == 1 ) {` is not picking up the content of the "data: 'Status'". Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to debug your **data** object in your browser console. If doesn't help, update your question with the content of your data object returned.

Comment: Hi and thanks for looking at this post. If I insert a console.log("DATA", data); any where in the script I get an error "Unexpected token '.'", any idea how I can read the content of data?

Comment: Did you check the "Network" tab in the "Inspect Page" of your browser to see what is the response to your ajax request?

Comment: the ajax response is [{"BoardName":"Main reception","Status":1}], which is what I would expect.

Comment: Try to comment everything else in **rowCallback** and try to console.log it. Another thing, the response is an array, but within the array it's an object, so ** data[1] == 1** pbbly wont work

Comment: Hi, done that and the console.log returns: {BoardName: "Main reception", Status: 1}
BoardName: "Main reception"
Status: 1

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. Since the console.log returns something, it means it has something. To access the status property to compare to 1, as you were trying to do before you should `if(data.Status == 1)`

Comment: Now its working. I did not know how to access the "Status" part of the array. Now you have pointed it out its perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Afonso. Could you update this answer with the results of the discussion? The answer is rather sparse at the moment, and does not seem to contain the details of the cause of problem, or what the fix was.